# How to replace specific values in a specific column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Take a list of codes formatted as strings, L, and a pandas dataframe, df:

```
list = ['A', 'D', 'G']
```

```
df = 

Code    Type    Score   Price
A        1       1.3     5
A        2       4.5     6
C        4       4.32    7
D        5       2.4     8
E        6       2       9
F        7       1.3     2
G        7       1       1
```

How can I replace values in in df['Price'] if df['Code'] is in list?

So in this instance I would want to change the first two lines the 4th line and the last line as they have codes that are in list.

I have another list that will have values in and the length of this list will be such that it is the number of values to replace, so in this example it would be of length 4. So the list could look like price_replace = [3,4,7,8] so the price in the first two rows becomes 3 and 4,.... as so on

I want to keep everything else the same.

I have tried

```
df.loc[df['Code'].isin(list)]
```

which generates pandas dataframe consisting of the rows I want to change, but I am not sure how to actually change them and then get the other lines of df unchanged.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well what do you want to change the values with?

Comment: @yatu why did you delete your post I wanted to mark as answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `numpy.where()` to do that.

`C = numpy.where('condition', x, y)`

`x` and `y` should be arrays.

Which means that `C` would be equal to `x` if condition returns `True` and `y` otherwise.

In your case:

```
df['Price'] = numpy.where(df['Code'] in list, ['Your value if true'], df['Price'])
```

This basically means that you will udpate the `Price` column by `'Your value if true'`  when a value in `Code` column exists in your `list` list else, it would retain the original value of the `Price` column.

Also, kindly avoid using `'list'` as variable name for a `list` object in python, that's bad practice :)).